# PHP Query: How to input data into 2 columns column on the same table at different times

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an application to save card and the barcode number to user card table.
But first, I just want to save the `card_id` and `user_id`.
And then after that, I will input barcode and barcode_format at different times.
This is the simulations :

I choose the card with card ID = 1
and my ID is = 3

My query is :

```
INSERT INTO user_card (user_id, card_id) VALUES(?, ?)
```

user_card Table :

```
id  card_id  user_id  barcode  barcode_format
1      1       3
```

and then, after the card that I choose is save in the table, I will add the barcode.

The question is, what's the best approach to do that ?

Is it possible ?

thanks :)

Comment: use a where clause in your insert statement to insert the barcode

Comment: @Jim You can't have a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` statement to modify the row.

Comment: @BarmarYour right, I mean an `UPDATE` statement.  Thanks

Comment: INSERT the first value, then UPDATE the record with the other value.

Comment: so, Should I use the update ?

Comment: thanks, already solved haha. I try to use INSERT INTO SELECT but it  didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way, Insert the row , get the last insert id , update the row by the last inserted id. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Update your table with the new data;

`UPDATE user_cad SET barcode = **** , barcode_format = **** WHERE id = X` (X in you example is 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE user_card
SET barcode = ?, barcode_format = ?
WHERE user_id = ? and card_id = ?;
```

Or

```
UPDATE user_card
SET barcode = ?, barcode_format = ?
WHERE id = ?;
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

- Store the ID somewhere;
- After get paremeters you want, `UPDATE` your table as you need with ID you stored.